# How can you add a legacy web reference to .net core project

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, .net-core, web-reference

I have a .net core project that I need to add a web reference to an older legacy web reference (written in vb.net)   Typically I would have selected service reference > advanced > add web reference.

I don't get those options in the .netcore project.  I do see a way to add a connected service and tried adding using a wcf but when I add the reference it shows the methods appended with "body", "response", and "requestbody"

How can I add an older legacy web reference in a .netcore project and access it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure these two things are not compatible with each other.  Your legacy web application is written in the older .NET Framework (what they now call ".NET Standard," I think).  I could be wrong, though.

Comment: What you call `legacy web reference` is a web service using a old version of SOAP that didn't support any of the WS-* interoperability standards and was replaced by newer standards in *2005*. You won't find built-in support for this in any IDE and I doubt any third-party libraries still work with this. Almost everyone migrated away from this in the last 16 years.

Comment: Given that nobody's going to build tools for ASMX services, the options are to either just work with `Body`, `Response` and `RequestBody` or work with HttpClient and XML directly. The amount of work may be the same either way - one of the things that changed in SOAP was the message envelope itself. The request and body classes you have may not be much help if their properties are opaque `object` types that need to be cast to the actual response type.